# is it possible to map multiple textures onto a shape in openGL ES?

Tags: iphone, android, opengl-es, texture-mapping, texture2d

Im new to `OpenGL ES` and wanted to create a bunch of triangles that would represent a grid of squares that i could map map tiles to. Is it possible to map separate textures on the same shape in OpenGL ES or would i have to make every square of the grid its own object? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency (read: to minimize texture binds) you probably want a [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas).

Bind your atlas texture, pass in your grid geometry with the proper texture coordinates, and you're good to go.